# How do I change this superclass into an abstract class without getting an instantiation exception?

Tags: java, javafx, abstract-class

I want to make my superclass an abstract class, however I am getting various exceptions when trying to do so (InstantiationException, RuntimeException, InvocationTargetException). My code works when I do not have my superclass as abstract. How do I fix this?

I have tried including my "main" and "start" functions outside of the abstract class body as I believed it may have been an issue calling these functions inside an abstract class. I moved these methods into a subclass which extends the abstract class. Then I overrode the abstract method "start" in each subclass. This reformatting did not solve anything though as I get the same errors. From what I've researched in this question [How do you call a subclass method from a superclass in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032463/how-do-you-call-a-subclass-method-from-a-superclass-in-java) the format this user uses is close to what I am trying to achieve with my abstract superclass extending "Application."

```
package tutorial.application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.lang.Math;


public abstract class Test extends Application{

    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;

    public Test() {
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0;
    }

    public Test(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract void draw(GraphicsContext GC);


    public class MyLine extends Test{

        private int x1, x2, y1, y2;

        public MyLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            super(0, 0);
            this.x1 = x1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.y2 = y2;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(GraphicsContext GC){
            GC.strokeLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        int canvasx = 400, canvasy = 650;
        MyLine line = new MyLine(0, 0, canvasx, canvasy);
        MyLine line2 = new MyLine(0, canvasy, canvasx, 0);
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasx, canvasy);
        GraphicsContext GC = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        line.draw(GC);
        line2.draw(GC);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

When I don't have my superclass as an abstract class and draw is no longer an abstract method, I get this which is my desired output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2tVt.png

However, otherwise I am getting the following error messages:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class tutorial.application.Test
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application tutorial.application.Test
```

Edit:
I have so far tried about 3 significantly different options all resulting with errors. Firstly I tried making the subclass static from within the hierarchy as follows:

```
static class MyLine extends Test{
.
.
.
}
```

I have also tried again to take the inner class "MyLine" out of the superclass "Test" as follows:

```
public abstract class Test extends Application{

    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;

    public Test() {
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0;
    }

    public Test(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract void draw(GraphicsContext GC);

    public static void main(String []args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        int canvasx = 400, canvasy = 650;
        MyLine line = new MyLine(0, 0, canvasx, canvasy);
        MyLine line2 = new MyLine(0, canvasy, canvasx, 0);
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasx, canvasy);
        GraphicsContext GC = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        line.draw(GC);
        line2.draw(GC);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class MyLine extends Test{

    private int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    public MyLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        super(0, 0);
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext GC){
        GC.strokeLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Laslty I designed a new class "Main" to extend "Test" and launching the application from there as follows:

```
package tutorial.application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.lang.Math;


public abstract class Test extends Application{

    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;

    public Test() {
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0;
    }

    public Test(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract void draw(GraphicsContext GC);


}

class MyLine extends Test{

    private int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    public MyLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        super(0, 0);
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext GC){
        GC.strokeLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {

    }
}

class Main extends Test{
    private Main() {
        super(0,0);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        int canvasx = 400, canvasy = 650;
        MyLine line = new MyLine(0, 0, canvasx, canvasy);
        MyLine line2 = new MyLine(0, canvasy, canvasx, 0);
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasx, canvasy);
        GraphicsContext GC = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        line.draw(GC);
        line2.draw(GC);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext GC) {

    }
}
```

The first two still result in the same errors and the last one I believe worsens my problem as it throws a new exception in thread "main":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: If you read the _javadoc_ for `InstantiationException` you will see that abstract classes cannot be instantiated via reflection. If you study the stack trace you posted, you will see that the code is trying to instantiate your `Test` class via reflection.

Comment: `launch` always starts the class containing the method calling `launch` (or similar) and that's the `Test` class. You could specify a diffent class as additional parameter to the `Launch` method. Note that `MyLine` won't work either, since it's a non-`static` inner class and therefore would require a parameter of the containing class to construct. (A constructor being able to be reflectively called passing no parameters is required.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can’t instantiate the subclass if the superclass is abstract is that the subclass is an *inner* class of the superclass and to instantiate an inner class you need an instance of the containing class, but by definition you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Make the subclass `static` and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Is there a reason MyLine would be an inner class of the abstract it inherits from? I mean, even if that works, what’s the point?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim it would only make sense if it referred to fields in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution by renaming my class file to be named "Main." This allowed me to keep the abstract class "Test" and all of it's sublclasses and I launched the Application through my new public class "Main" which extends "Application."